# Is it dangerous to use Auto Sensor Cleaning with lens attached?

Tags: sensor, equipment-damage, cleaning, maintenance

Straightforward question:
Is it dangerous to use auto sensor cleaning when the lens is attached?

Comment: Why do you think this *might* be a problem?

Comment: @PhilipKendall: I'm not a pro, so I thought maybe the sensor would touch the back of the lens when it shakes which appears to be not happening based on the answer to this question.

Comment: There's a mirror in the way :-)

Comment: @PhilipKendall: Forgot to mention, using a mirror-less :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It's fine; I can't imagine why there might be a problem. Automatic sensor cleaning generally works by shaking the sensor a small amount at high frequency. This doesn't get anywhere near the lens (at least, not more than the sensor already is). I guess it's mildly possible that some dust might end up transmitted to the rear element of the lens, but that's okay — that's easily cleanable.

Many cameras can be set to (or even defaults to) automatic cleaning when the camera is turned on, or off, or both. It's difficult to imagine that camera makers expect no lens to be mounted at this time (in fact quite the contrary), so we know for sure that it's designed to operate this way.

Comment: If you could see the auto sensor cleaning happening, would the human eye be able to detect any movement?

Comment: That would make an excellent question.

Comment: @jdv done. At a vibration frequency of up to 50KHz, I think I can guess the answer